# Using external libraries for model training in aws sagemaker

Tags: python, amazon-sagemaker

I am just getting started with aws sagemaker and realized it doesn't have a random forest classifier. I found this github tutorial on creating your own and deploying it in sagemaker: https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/main/sagemaker-python-sdk/scikit_learn_randomforest/Sklearn_on_SageMaker_end2end.ipynb.

I am using the python sdk and was more or less curious to see if anyone actually uses this or any external libraries for training with sagemaker. It seems that if you aren't using the built in algorithms then it is very involved to create your own and the functionality of the model and ability to interpret it is very limited once you do get it trained.

For example after deploying the model to an aws endpoint and pulling down the artifacts I could only call the `predict` method (no `predict_probab` as is possible in the actual `sklearn randomforestclassifier`). I also haven't been able to find anything like what you get in `sklearn.metrics` such as `accuracy_score, roc_auc_score, precision_score, recall_score, f1_score, confusion_matrix` etc so I'm assuming one would need to build equivalents to these from scratch to be able to interpret their model.

I have spent a week or so researching this and trying to get this rigged up and it just seems that importing external libraries for model training in sagemaker is not very popular or well-documented online. Interested to know if I'm just unaware of more functionality or if there are alternatives that people prefer or if I should just stick with the built in xgboost classifier if I am looking for a tree-based option. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to add extra packages for training when using any of the Framework containers such as SKLearn. Kindly see this [link](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/frameworks/sklearn/using_sklearn.html#using-third-party-libraries) for more information.

From a hosting perspective, you do have the ability to provide a custom entry_point / inference.py script that you can use to control model loading, pre and post processing. Please see this [link](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/frameworks/sklearn/using_sklearn.html#load-a-model) for more information